# How to alter a column name in an Ecto model with a migration?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Does anyone know of (or can provide) an example of how to alter a table column name using the ecto DSL

I'm guessing I just use mix ecto.gen.migration but then would I just fill in the empty created file with my custom code (if so, how would you edit a column name, the docs show modify to change the column type)

or is there a command line flag I can pass to generate the migration code for me?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can now do that with [`Ecto.Migration.rename/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#rename/3):

```
rename table(:posts), :title, to: :summary
```

Comment: Works as it should.

Comment: I'm guessing that the reason this doesn't work for me is we still have MySql 5, so I think this answer is applicable to MySql 8 or higher.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have an option to rename columns yet. You will need to consult your database documentation and issue a SQL statement with `execute`.

Comment: OK cool, I'll create the blank migration and add my own SQL :)